# ResultInterface Error

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, magento2.2.6

we are noticing a strange behaviour on a CE 2.2.6 which we can't interpret. We didn't do any updates, it's possible that an OpCache/Redis flush let come up an error from an update before. Each time we are calling a URL in an XHR Request with a timestamp included like ?_=1540374954091, we are receiving an Error 500 from nginx.

If we replace the underscore with a regular var name like ?a=b the error doesn't come up, so there's a possible relation with non-cachable requests.

The log says:

```
2018/10/24 14:20:06 [error] 2924#2924: *2225 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin::afterRenderResult() must implement interface Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin->afterRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json\Interceptor), NULL, Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#2 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Controller/Result/Json/Interceptor.php(91): Magento\F" while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.131.xx.xxx, server: www.xxx.com, request: "GET /popup/Popup/Index/?_=1540374954091 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "www.xxx.com"
```

It's a composer based installation, the Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface is in place. Any ideas how to debug etc.?

Thanks
Jan

Comment: Welcome Friend to Magento Stackexchange, Are you facing this on every page?

Comment: Thanks Ramkishan! Yes and no. I could trigger it on each page by adding a get var like ?_=whatever to the URL. You can see it live at
https://www.makerdise.com/?_=test. If you visit another page like home regularly with open dev console, you can see the XHR call to the popup controller resulting in error 500.

Comment: ok let me check if I can generate it on my local.

Comment: I tested some other systems, no error like in our case at

http://mag2opensource.basecom.de/?_=123
https://magento.nublue.co.uk/?_=123

In our backend section, we aren't facing that... STRANGE

Comment: Maybe related to wrong class mapping? I can't find out why  interface Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface is null in this case.

Answer (score 1):

We found a bug in a 3rd party module (Mirasvit_Seo).

Comment: What kind of bug is this? Can you please explain more. It'll be helpful for others.

Comment: For sure: a newly introduced plugin (Mirasvit\Seo\Plugin\ChangeResult\ChangeContent) extends the ResultInterface . The class has a method called  afterRenderResult, it will bring up an error in case of attached underscores in the querystring,  affecting the complete Interface.

Comment: most welcome, Always happy to help everyone.